# How to create a default association in an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails 3.2 I'm trying to set a default `OdontologicUnity` instace when a `User` is created.

User:

```
require "odontological_unity"
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :odontologic_unity, ...
    ...

    belongs_to :odontologic_unity

    after_create :associate_default_unity

    private 
    def associate_default_unity
      ou = OdontologicUnity::DEFAULT
      ou.save!
      self.update_attribute :odontologic_unity, ou
    end

end
```

OdontologicUnity:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class OdontologicUnity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  DEFAULT = OdontologicUnity.new(
    name: 'Actualiza el nombre',
    address: 'Actualiza la dirección',
    nit: 'Actualiza el NIT',
    mission: "Actualiza la misión",
    vision: "Actualiza la visión"
  )
end
```

The code works without raising exceptions but when I see to my DB I got this (`odontological_unity_id: nil`):

`User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
 => #<User id: 9, email: "user2@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$BPDmM6stW0sO6tQbwwJCxuWO4hvWIAeSzogEl2GGiqmo...", remember_token: "ltU5RBcifDsr9uPIci9z_A", names: "Example User", lastnames: "Some Lastnames", identity_document_number: "1515", odontological_unity_id: nil, created_at: "2012-06-24 15:00:17", updated_at: "2012-06-24 15:02:05">`

The weird thing about it is the `OdontologicUnity` record is actually created, but doesn't get associated with the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use a method for creating a default user, not a constant. Regarding your problem, try a before create instead and assign the id:

```
before_create :associate_default_unity

def associate_default_unity
  ou = OdontologicUnity::DEFAULT
  ou.save!
  self.write_attribute :odontologic_unity_id, ou.id
end
```